# Python + OpenCV: OCR of characters with vertical lines in between

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am trying to make Optical Character Recognition from mobile-taken photos. After the first phase of pre-processing, I have an image like the one as follows:

[image]

The first problem I have is that it is rotated, which I solved it with the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def rotateImage(image):
    inverse = (255-image)
    lines = cv2.HoughLines(inverse, 2, np.pi/180, 100)
    angle = lines[0][0][1]

    shape = (image.shape[1], image.shape[0])
    image_center = tuple(np.array(shape)/2)
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center,-angle,1.0)
    result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, shape,flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return result

img = cv2.imread('image.png', 0)

rotated = rotateImage(img)
cv2.imshow('rotated', rotated)
```

This basically finds the angle of the horizontal line below the characters, and makes a rotation of the image with that angle.

However, my main problem now is that when I try to make OCR, the vertical lines are sometimes read as 'l' or '1'. What approach would you make in order to delete those vertical lines and/or making OCR with them between characters?

Things that must be taken into account:

1. The rotation is not perfect, so we cannot assume that the lines are complitelly vertical.
2. Sometimes the characters are touching the lines, which difficults the detection of them.

Comment: Maybe, find the distance between two lines and then removes them by adding a white rectangle above ?

Comment: As those lines are perpendicular to the horizontal one, it can be done pretty easily.

Comment: Once you have rotated the image, sum each column black pixels and if sum>threshold delete column or make it all white. Threshold would be image height or just bigger than max letter height. 
Or another approach would be to start at any black pixel of the long horizontal line and perform a recursion on it as long as there's a neighbor black pixel, move to it and make it white.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @Elia. I thaught about the approach but sometimes the characters are touching the line and, therefore, they'd be removed. I'll try your first approach, although if the rotation is not made perfectly may have some problems.

Comment: Try using HoughLinesP from OpenCV. Calculate the angle from the start-end point of the vertical line to be sure it is what you are looking for and make all pixels along this/these column/s as white. If the characters are touching the line, you can use morphological operation before binarizing the image for HoughLine